# Unit test RxJava Observables

Tags: rx-java

I am new to RxJava. I have written Observable which is calling a rest api using restTemplate. I want to unit test my Observables created in service class.
I am aware of unit testing the rest api controller and service class using MockMVC. So need help on how to test my async endpoints in controller and Observalbes in service class using Mockito or MockMVC or any framework available.

Here is my code

> SampleController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public DeferredResult<List<Response>> getresponse() {
        DeferredResult<List<Response>> response = new DeferredResult<>();
            service
              .fetchJson()
              .subscribe(result -> response.setResult(result));
        return response;
    }
```

> Service.java

```
@Override
    public Observable<List<Response>> fetchJson() {
        Observable<List<Response>> list = Observable.<List<Response>>create(
                subscriber -> subscriber.onNext(this.invokeRestCall(APIURL)))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executor));*/
        return list;
    }
private List<Response> invokeRestCall(String APIURL) {  

    Response[] responses = restTemplate.getForObject(APIURL, Response[].class);
    return Arrays.stream(responses).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Please put a unit test case if anyone has written for testing controller endpoint which is async as well as for Observable in service class.

Answer (score 0):

One way I know is to inject the schedulers, and that way when you are testing just inject Schedulers.trampoline() to all schedulers and that way your test will run on the same thread.